# Low transfer speed on local network over a router

Tags: router, file-transfer, network-adapter

I am using a wireless router (linksys WRT45G).
I have a desktop with a network adapter and a laptop.
The desktop is using vista, while 7 on the laptop.

I have shared directories on the desktop which im goin to use on my Lap.
But the tranfer speed is just 250 kbytes-ps which drops down to asa low as 120.
I know this is a very low speed.
Where the problem might be??
I tried connecting devices with Lan wires. but didnt help.

HELP!!

Comment: Where did you get the speeds you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Connecting them both to the router does not guarantee the laptop is now using the Ethernet link, the wireless may still have had priority. I'd check in the router configuration to make sure the wireless transmission speed is not limited.

Also keep in mind that due to the overhead of wireless transmission (and the speeds of the wireless technologies), you aren't going to achieve the same speed as you would on a wired network.

Comment: You can look at the task manager network tab during a transfer to see which network is active.

Answer (score 0):

It depends quite a bit on how many files are in the directory and how big they are.  Lots of small files will not transfer as fast as a single large one with same data (think a zip archive) because the receiving computer spends a lot of time creating a new directory entry for each of the many new files before it transfers the data.  This directory overhead can make a big difference, especially if your disk random access rate isn't great.  Try zipping the files first and see if that makes a difference.

Also try to get a baseline speed by transferring something like a 700 MB ISO file just for reference purposes.  If you're copying from the desktop to the laptop you'll probably find it slower than going the other way because laptop drives usually (but not always) spin slower and have fewer bits under the heads on each revolution.